# Make a script run each frame and reset when returning to start

Tags: python

Struggling to get started with frame handling for my simulation so I've made the most basic example to ask for help

In this example, I want to move the mesh vertices 0.1m per frame. I want the mesh to go back to the start when i press shift+rightarrow to navigate the timeline back to start.

This is my attempt but it doesn't reset.

Ideally, I would like to cache the changes as i go, like blender's physics sim does. Can anyone tell me how that works? thanks

```
import bpy

# Define a function to update the mesh per frame
def frame_handler(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current  # Get the current frame
    mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object
    mesh_object_initial = mesh_object
    
    if frame == 1:
        mesh = mesh_object_initial.data

    else:

        mesh = mesh_object.data
        
        # Modify the mesh based on the current frame (e.g., move vertices)
        for vertex in mesh.vertices:
            vertex.co.z += 0.1  # Move vertices along the Z-axis
        

        
    # Update the mesh to reflect the 
    mesh.update()
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()

# Register the frame-change handler
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider storing all frame data into global variables

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj_name = obj.name
# store frame 1 data if current frame is 1
verts_init = [vert.co.copy() for vert in obj.data.vertices]
old_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

def sim(old_frame, new_frame):
    obj = bpy.data.objects[obj_name]

    if new_frame == old_frame: return
    if new_frame > old_frame:
        for _ in range(new_frame - old_frame):
            for vertex in obj.data.vertices:
                vertex.co.z += 0.1
    else:
        # do backward or do from frame 1
        for _ in range(old_frame - new_frame):
            for vertex in obj.data.vertices:
                vertex.co.z -= 0.1

    bpy.context.view_layer.update()



# Define a function to update the mesh per frame
def frame_handler(scene):
    global old_frame
    new_frame = max(1, scene.frame_current)
    sim(old_frame, new_frame)
    old_frame = new_frame


# Register the frame-change handler
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(frame_handler)
```

Other Example Using cache

```
import bpy
from bisect import bisect

objects = bpy.data.objects
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj_name = obj.name

cache = {}
def store(frame):
    cache[frame] = [vert.co.copy() for vert in objects[obj_name].data.vertices]
    
# suppose current frame is 1
store(1)
old_frame = 1

def sim_1_frame():
    for vertex in objects[obj_name].data.vertices:
        vertex.co.z += 0.1

def sim(old_frame, new_frame):
    if new_frame == old_frame: return

    if new_frame in cache:
        for co, vert in zip(cache[new_frame], objects[obj_name].data.vertices):
            vert.co = co

        bpy.context.view_layer.update()
        return

    if new_frame > old_frame:
        for _ in range(new_frame - old_frame):
            sim_1_frame()
    else:
        # find nearest prev frame in cache
        lis = [k for k in cache]
        lis.sort()
        i = bisect(lis, new_frame)
        f = lis[i - 1]

        for co, vert in zip(cache[f], objects[obj_name].data.vertices):
            vert.co = co
        for _ in range(new_frame - f):
            sim_1_frame()

    store(new_frame)
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()



# Define a function to update the mesh per frame
def frame_handler(scene):
    global old_frame
    new_frame = max(1, scene.frame_current)
    sim(old_frame, new_frame)
    old_frame = new_frame


# Register the frame-change handler
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(frame_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting. It works really well for this simple example I asked for but I actually intended to do a physics sim. Calculating backwards seems excessive.

Blender turns the timeline blue and caches past frames. Is this functionality in the python api? many thanks again really helpful answer.

Comment: It has `bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()`; `bpy.ops.ed.undo()` and redo to restore the data, But it may not be suitable for your situation. You can store the vertex data to the variable for each sim at specific frame and don't need to recompute it again when you enter the same frame.

Comment: This is brilliant thanks! My update function needs to update positions and velocities from previous frames. Should i do another cache for velocities?

I've been converting the mesh data to and from  numpy arrays. should I do the conversion in the update function or store the cache as a numpy matrix and convert back in the frame handling function?

thanks again this is just the help I needed.

Comment: Both storage types are available, depending on which is more convenient for you. You can use the `time` module to check which one is faster.